# How to get word before and after the current word in a file?

Tags: c, file, replace, words

I have a file, "data.txt" that consists of the following: http://pastebin.com/FY9ZTQX6

I'm trying to get the word before and after the "<". The old word being the one on the left and the new word being the one on the right. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*
Name: Marcus Lorenzana
Assignment: Final
*/

//binary tree struct to hold left and right node
//as well as the word and number of occurrences
typedef struct node
{
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}
node;

//,.?!:;-
int punctuation[7];


void insert(node ** dictionary, node * entry);
char* readFile(char* filename);
void printDictionary(node * tree);
void toLower(char** word);
void getReplacementWords(char *filecontents, char **newWord, char **oldWord)  ;


int main()
{

    char *word;
    char* filecontents = readFile("data.txt");
    char* oldWord;
    char* newWord;

    //create dictionary node
    node *dictionary;
    node *entry;

    //read words and punctuation in from the text file
    word = strtok (filecontents, " \n");

    dictionary = NULL;

    while (word != NULL)
    {
        //word = strlwr(word); 
        entry = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
        entry->left = entry->right = NULL;
        entry->word = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(word)+1));
        entry->word = word;
        insert(&dictionary,entry);
        word = strtok (NULL, " \n");
    }

    //printDictionary(dictionary);

    filecontents = readFile("data.txt"); 
    getReplacementWords(filecontents,&newWord,&oldWord);




    return 0;
}

void insert(node ** dictionary, node * entry)
{
    if(!(*dictionary))
    {
        *dictionary = entry;
        entry->count=1;
        return;
    }


    int result = strcmp(entry->word,(*dictionary)->word);

    if(result<0){
        insert(&(*dictionary)->left, entry);
        entry->count++; 
    }
    else if(result>0){
        insert(&(*dictionary)->right, entry);
        entry->count++; 
    } else {
        entry->count++; 
    }

}

//put file contents in string for strtok
char* readFile(char* filename)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(filename,"r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long int size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    char* content = calloc(size + 1, 1);

    fread(content,1,size,file);

    return content;
}

void printDictionary(node * dictionary)
{
    if(dictionary->left) {
        printDictionary(dictionary->left);
    }

    printf("%s\n",dictionary->word);

    if(dictionary->right) {
        printDictionary(dictionary->right);
    }
}


void getReplacementWords(char *filecontents, char **newWord, char **oldWord) {
    char *word;
    word = strtok (filecontents, " \n");

    while (word != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%s",word); 
        int result = strcmp(word,"<"); 
        if (result == 0) {
            printf("\nFound replacement identifier"); 
        }
        word = strtok (NULL, " \n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use
`fscanf(filename , "%s < %s" , firstStringContainer , secondStringContainer)`

after using `fseek` to get to the line containing the `<` character this will get the string before the < to be stored in `firstStringContaine`r and the one after in `secondStringContainer`
here's a code a recommand you to use :

```
int found = 0;
char buffer[chooseYourSize];
char firstStringContainer[chooseYourSize] , secondStringContainer[chooseYourSize];
while(fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , filename) != NULL)
{
    if(strchr(buffer , '<'))
    {
         found++;
         break;
    }
}
if(found)
{
     fscanf(file , "%s < %s" , firstStringContainer , secondStringContainer);
}
```

of course this only works if the lines targeted only contains the three elements string < string which is the case here

Comment: That might not work if he has it located elsewhere, maybe preceded by other information relative to this.  It's better to make code more general to deal with a variety of inputs.  Since the input dictates the program not vice versa.

Comment: I most certainly agree with you , but this is just one way of doing it.

Comment: Works! Thank you. It was difficult choosing an answer haha. Thanks everbody.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in the format of STRING1 < STRING2 you can do:

```
fscanf(file,"%s < %s", string1, string2);
```

if it's somewhere on a line it's going to be a little more difficult.  What you can do is grab lines from the file and put them into a buffer, then locate the `>`, go back to the beginning of the first string, and read what you want.

```
while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),file) != NULL 
{
    if( (pointer = strstr(buff," > ")) != NULL) 
     {
        //now you have located the > just go back 
        //in the buff till you reach the start of 
        //string1 and then use
        sscanf(buff+(pointer * sizeof(char)),"%s > %s",string1, string2)
     }
}
```

it's been a while since I did this so there might be syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fseek()` in a loop to skip 1 element forward/back and verify if it is `space` or `>` or `other needed character` (another function from **string.h**).

When you find this symbol, you can move the pointer forward/back to another `space` or `other needed character`, remember the number of skipped characters **N** and then copy **N** symbols to a string variable.

```
substitute < replacement
           ^ find this symbol

substitute < replacement
          ^ make a loop that  makes `counter++` when it finds `space`
            (int counter  = 0;)

 substitute < replacement
^ the loop will continue and will find the 2nd `space`, and make `counter++`
  when `counter == 2` (1 space after and 1 before the word) the loop stops. 
  Now `file` pointer points to the `space` symbol before the 1st word.
  Then skip 1 element forward (using `fseek()`) and now you have
  `file` pointer that points to the 1st word.
  And now you can do whatever you want!
```

Do the same actions to find the 2nd word (`file` pointer will point to the 2nd word so you will be able to call this function again: it will be looking for thw 2nd `>` in your text) and make a function `findWordsNearArrow()` or something like that.

You can call this function in a loop so when it finds `EOF` it will return specific value that you can use to exit the loop.

Think again. (c)

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()` and `strchr()` to get to the line with the `<`.

```
while (strchr (fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), file), '<') == NULL)
     ;       // do nothing
```

Then use `strtok()` to parse the current line in the buffer

```
strcpy (oldword, strtok (buffer, "<"));
strcpy (newword, strtok (NULL, "\n"));
```